# How to align included layout bottom in android?

Tags: android

I have layout included inside another layout , I want this included one aligned bottom when I include it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<Button 
        android:text="Enter Piano course" 
        android:id="@+id/btnEnterCourse" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>

<include 
                layout="@layout/powered_by_bar"></include>
</LinearLayout>
```

in this code sample I want to align `powered_by_bar` to the bottom of the interface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a vertical LinearLayout you cannot align at bottom (or at top) but left or right. In horizontal LinearLayout you can align bottom and top but not left or right.

To do that you have to wrap the inner LinearLayout in a horizontal LinearLayout and set the layout_weight and layout_gravity correctly:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <Button android:text="Enter Piano course" 
                    android:id="@+id/btnEnterCourse" 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>

            <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="1" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
                    <LinearLayout android:background="#0000ff" android:layout_gravity="bottom" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="30dip" />
            </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use RelativeLayout,it is more efficient than LinearLayout and it has many attributes to align the items as we want.You can use those RelativeLayout attributes in "include" tag also.
from android developer site "**Similarly, you can override all the layout parameters. This means that any android:layout_* attribute can be used with the  tag.**" see  http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-reuse.html